# Upgrading TargetFramework in multi project C# solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, upgrade, .net-standard

I will admit up front I have been coding for 20+ years and never really understood the whole dot net standard/core/net567.0 thing.  I have a xamarin forms solution with 6 projects in it.  There is some netstandard2.1, netcoreapp3.1 and the mono iOS and android libraries.  I would like to bring everything up to date with net7.0 if possible, but an earlier version if necessary.  I don't fancy moving to Maui just yet.

I believe all my nugets are fairly up to date so how do I upgrade?  I have changed

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and the various other versions but that just throws up errors about monodroid v12 not supporting that dot net versions.

Comment: check the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez thanks.  I am tryingt he upgrade-assistant but it doesn't seem to do anything.  the upgrade option doesn't suggest anything or make any changes and when i turn on the -v option there are lots of errors as it runs.

Comment: i also found this link, it might be useful https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-migrate-from-net-core-3-1-to-net-6-0/

Comment: What is the complete error message about monodroid v12 not supporting that dot net versions? .NET Upgrade Assistant is only for migrating from .NET Framework to .NET6.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I gave up in the end.  upgrade-assistant turned out to be a good excuse to clean my dev machine and get rid of some of the cruft from the project files.  However I think MSFT want you to go from xamarin.forms to maui if you want the latest features and i'm not that desperate.